# facebook like box external css

Tags: iframe, facebook

I need to customize the layout for the Like box, the problem i am getting is i coud not find any way to do it in following iframe,

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%platform&width=700&connections=5&stream=false&header=false&height=180&css=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fq.css" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:700px; height:180px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

The earlier facebook like box had option to load external css, i tried it but it is not getting uploaded with th above iframe options.

WHere can i find the solution

Please help me setting external css to this.

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried linking a Likebox to a local css file and was unsuccessful. In researching this question somewhere on the Facebook fora I read an admin's post saying Facebook wants to maintain consistent formatting across Like boxes so only a few properties can be adjusted, and those are the standard ones you get in the initial Like box code. Facebook's documentation leaves a lot to be desired.

Jim

Answer (score 4):

You can still use the css option but you have to use a different iframe URL:

```
http://www.connect.facebook.com/widgets/fan.php?href=FACEBOOKPAGEURL&amp;width=185&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=false&amp;header=true&amp;height=280&amp;css=CSSFILE
```

**Edit 14-3-2013**

This workaround no longer works.

Comment: Note: All attributes are same, so the poster is right, substitute `http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php` with `http://www.connect.facebook.com/widgets/fan.php` and it just works.

Comment: yes, that uses the old fanbox. The CSSFILE thing that you specify should be a publicly accessible URL.  Facebook then injects into the html source for the iframe, a `<link>` to that css stylesheet. In my experience, it is not a direct link, but it is a link to `http://...fbcdn.net/fbml_static_get.php?...` which is a PHP app that retrieves your publicly-accessible CSS, then massages it and caches it. But FB said that all FBML endpoints would die on June 1 2012. https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/ . Therefore, probably this approach will work for only a few more months.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to style de Like box too, but the new plugin does not support the "css=" option in the iframe.

I still use the old Like box plugin, but the CSS is cached and I cannot update it.

```
http://www.facebook.com/connect/connect.php?id=60159065762&amp;connections=0&amp;stream=0&amp;css=http%3A%2F%2Fdescargas.mundijuegos.com%2Fcss%2Ffb2.css%3F12
```

The only way I know you can use your own CSS right now is using the script format with the ["fb:fan" plugin](http://www.rocketpopmedia.com/blog/how-to-style-the-facebook-like-box-using-css/comment-page-1/#comment-266).

**Updated**

if you use the "fb:fan" plugin, it generates an iframe . You can copy this URL and use it directly (http://www.facebook.com/plugins/fan.php?....).

Comment: It's easy to work around the cache. You need to specify a different CSS URL each time the page loads.  One way to do it is to echo the CSS from a PHP program.  For the CSS URL you give to facebook, pass the URL to the PHP program, with a dummy query parameter and a randomly generated value associated to it.  `http:.//example.com/generateCss.php?_=309339`.  Because this is a unique URL each time, FB will not cache the CSS.  But this approach may stop working anyway, because it depends on a FBML program on the FB side, and FBML is being turned off on June 1 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook no longer support css. All facebook design hacks using css will no longer work. However, facebook now allows the likebox plugin to be rendered *without a border* via the **show_border=false** argument. 
But if you want to add some color gradients to background of your like box for matching your blog's colorful theme, you can SVG. Read this guide - http://www.howtokickblogger.com/2013/08/style-facebook-like-box-with-svg.html