# fb:like-box, custom css?

Tags: html, facebook, api, facebook-likebox

Is it possible to add a custom css file to a fb:like-box? For example, I would like to remove the borders around the iframe. Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The new like-box does not accept the "css" attribute. You have to use the old fb:fan plugin to achieve it.

For example:

```
<fb:fan profile_id='[PAGE_ID]' width='300' height='256' show_faces='true' stream='false' header='false' css='[CSS_URL]'></fb:fan>
```

Remember to add the "all.js".

Comment: More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518024/facebook-like-box-external-css/4852787#4852787

Comment: This method appears to have stopped working a few days ago. Here's an alternative, very similar approach: http://pixabay.com/de/blog/posts/how-to-style-a-facebook-like-box-with-css-30/

Comment: And now a month later, their next approach is also broken. It's safe to say the custom css thing is dead for good.

Comment: This approach for customizing the Facebook Like Box fails. Facebook aims at providing a consistent user experience and has removed all available options for injecting a custom CSS stylesheet into this widget.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">FB.init("Your-App-ID");</script>

<fb:fan profile_id="Your-Page-Profile-ID" connections="20" width="300" height="300" css="http://example.com/likebox-style.css?1"></fb:fan>
```

Don't use live stream for pages with low post rate, the stream will be empty if there are only posts older than 6 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `css` attribute to the `<fb:like-box>` tag with a href to your custom CSS stylesheet. This will allow you to manipulate the existing styles.

A good article on this subject: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-add-a-custom-facebook-like-box-to-your-site

Comment: Ive tried that, but when i change <fb:like-box> to <fb:fan>, the box disappears.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook like box no longer supports css. Facebook reports:
    Support for custom CSS has been removed due to security implications. We now allow the likebox plugin to be rendered **without a border** via the **show_border=false** argument.
However, if you like to make your like box colorful you can use the svg gradient trick. Read - [Styling Facebook Like Box With SVG](https://web.archive.org/web/20140702194020/http://www.howtokickblogger.com/2013/08/style-facebook-like-box-with-svg.html)

Answer (score 0):

More information about the topic:

If you want to use the force_wall attribute, you'll need to use the iframe version.

Basically:

Go to:

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/
- Get the iframe code
- Add the profile_id and css attributes to it (like explained above)
- Change the path from www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php? to http://www.connect.facebook.com/widgets/fan.php?...

**DONE**