# Styling a Facebook Like Box (HTML5 version)

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-likebox

Im using the HTML5 version of the Like Box, and I was wondering, how could I give it special styles? I tried adding a css="www.mydomain.com/mystyles.css" to the tag, but that didnt work.

Anyone can please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `css` for [Like Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) social plugin is not documented anymore. And doesn't work with new version of Like Box.

You may want to try use older version as suggested in answer to: [fb:like-box, custom css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874755/fblike-box-custom-css)

Comment: Where did I say like button? Im talking all the time about the like box

Comment: Oh, sorry about it (probably answered too fast ;) Updated the answer to respect the question.

Comment: I do have to point out that FBML is deprecated, and all FBML will fail starting june 1, 2012 : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/